# Show threads count from Parallel Stack

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

When I use

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count
```

it shows me from 9-12 threads (after WinForm app start)
but when I pause debugging and open Parallel Stack Window (VS2010) it shows 4 threads:
3 Threads External Code
1 Program.Main

Is it possible to show in my app the same number of threads which is in PST Window?

Comment: Do you have both the managed and native debuggers enabled?  Maybe this explains the discrepancy.

Comment: I tested this; the Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count value is 7, At the "Parallel Stacks" window If I "Enable unmanaged code debugging" then it shows me 6 threads, if it disabled then it shows me 4 threads. still one thread is missing :)